# How to set up the Raspberry Pi

Tags: boot, linux, raspbian-wheezy

I have just gotten my Raspberry Pi. I am a beginner in Linux.

Can someone please explain how I should go about starting up my computer?

Comment: Hi there. This question is probably too broad to be useful to future visitors. From the [faq]: "questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: @Jivings - Sorry, this was meant to be an example question; not a real one.

Comment: I understand that, but in no way does that make it exempt from the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, welcome to Pi Land. We have been expecting you :)

1. To start, you need to buy a [4 GB or higher SD card.](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=sd%20card)
2. Next, you must put a Rasbperry Pi Compatible OS on the card.

   a. **Windows**

   I recommend that you start with [Raspbian Wheezy](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/download.php?file=/images/raspbian/2012-12-16-wheezy-raspbian/2012-12-16-wheezy-raspbian.zip). On Windows, download [Win 32 Disk Imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) and [follow the prompts](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/quick-start-guide-v1.1.pdf).

   b. **Mac**

   The process is just as simple on the mac. Download the applescript program [Pi Filler](http://ivanx.com/raspberrypi/) and follow the prompts.
3. The rest is simple. Once you have written the SD card, insert it into the Pi's SD card slot. Now, connect your display and input (keyboard, mouse). Assuming you are using the Model B, connect an ethernet cable to the receiver. Lastly, plug in the micro USB. The Raspberry Pi should turn on.

If you need any more help, please see some of the resources around the net.

1. [Official PDF startup guide](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/quick-start-guide-v1.1.pdf)
2. [More SD card setup help](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Copying_an_image_to_the_SD_card_in_Mac.C2.A0OS.C2.A0X_.28Only_with_graphical_interface.29)

I hope that that was helpful!